# Finding the equation for ellipse velocity

Tags: calculus, parametric

I am trying to figure out how to do a homework problem for my math class. The homework for the night is, given a set of parametric equations, has three parts, the first of which is to find the speed of the ellipse at time t. The two parametric equations are $-6 \cos t = V_x$ and $4 \sin t = V_y$. From this, I have figured out that the ellipse will be 6 units wide and 4 units tall, and my "planet" will go around the origin starting at (-6, 0) and will traveling clockwise, but I get stuck here.

The second task is to determine the vertical and horizontal components of the velocity at angle $\theta$, which I have absolutely no idea how to do. I would greatly appreciate any help offered and am not looking for a solution; just a push in the right direction (it might have to be a pretty big push though; I have been lost in math for some time now and would greatly appreciate any good explanations of concepts involved.)

Comment: Can you calculate $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$? How might you use those?

Comment: He has taught us nothing about derivatives in this context (or at all), but I would greatly appreciate an explanation.

Comment: The setup is not like Kepler's laws of planetary motion, but if your variable $t$ is time, then the velocity is a directed quantity obtained by differentiating $(x,y)$, and speed would be the Euclidean norm of the velocity.

Comment: Please explain what the Euclidean norm of the velocity is.

Comment: Can you give the title of your textbook ?

Comment: We don't have one :/ and now you understand my dilemma.

Comment: What are you studying ?

Comment: I don't know! The class title is AP Calculus BC, but I'm not really sure what I'm doing and the teacher's explanations don't help at all.

Comment: Did you see this formula for the speed: $v=\sqrt{\dot x ^2+\dot y ^2}$ ?

Comment: Something like that; he wrote something about $\sqrt{V_x^2 + V_y^2}$ being the speed, but this doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: It does, though. It's the norm of the velocity vector (sometimes called "tangent vector" too), which itself is $(V_x,V_y)$, where $V_x=dx/dt$ and $V_y=dy/dt$. The euclidian norm of a vector with coordinates $(x,y)$ is simply $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and the "scalar valocity" is the norm of the "vector velocity".

Comment: Also, as hardmath pointed, you won't get the speed of a planet in elliptic motion, since the parametrization of the ellipse would absolutely not be the same: you would have to consider a motion with acceleration toward one of the focus (which would represent the Sun). Not true with the equation $x=a\cos t, y=b\sin t$.